# Docker - Running .Net Framework 4.5 Application

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

So I decided to dabble a little bit in the world of containers. I'm used to running VMs, but after learning more about containers I can see much better use of resources than VMs. So in my process of trying to get away from VMs so I setup a dev environment and all.

Anyways, let me get to the real point... I have been combing through hours of videos and tutorials. I have learned a fair amount from this and setting up asp core and IIS. However, I struggle to be able to setup a image with net framework 4.5 (Can be 4.5.2, doesn't matter) to running my application because it is targeted to run on net framework 4.5. I've used a few different based images in my dockerfile, but I am just not having any luck on finding the right base image to use. I've been searching on docker hub, but honestly, I have had some issue finding out version and everything on the site.

EDIT:

So, I am basically setting up a few servers and I am copying the files over. I'm not exposing any ports or anything at the moment because I figured if the server ran, the container will stay up indefinitely rather than shutdown. The server will throw an error if the port is already bound too. I'm not sure if I don't expose the port if it can bind to it or not. 
Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

SHELL ["powershell"]

COPY unturned C:/servers/unturned

ENTRYPOINT ["C:/servers/unturned/Unturned.exe", "-nographics", "-batchmode", "+secureserver/test"]
```

Comment: You must follow a tutorial like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc as .NET Framework requires Windows Docker images on Server Core.

Comment: [aspnet image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet/). You can use image with latest framework version as it's backward-compatible with `.NET Framework 4.5`

Comment: Also, can you please specify what error(s) you get when trying to run inside docker container?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, everyone. So as an update in here, I have used the aspnet image and it was returning me an error with w3svc has failed to start. So it is trying to run an IIS for some reason... Probably because it is aspnet. I'll post my docker file in the edit to get a better understanding.